# Error publishing to Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, tomcat6, publishing

I wave problem with Tomcat when I try to run a jsf page, I get next error:

[image]

Details:

```
 Publishing the configuration...
 Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat6.0/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
 Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/backup\catalina.properties: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
 Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/backup\context.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
 Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/backup\server.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
 Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/backup\tomcat-users.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
 Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/backup\web.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Who have same error? How to solve it? I try few hours, but no result :(

I have switch the location 
And set Use Tomcat installations but
also no result

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that if you run Eclipse as normal user, Eclipse doesn't have access to 
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation.. and doesnt copy the configuration file into backup.. 
Solution:
You have to run Eclipse As Administrator or to set in some way that when you click the Eclipse 
icon to run Eclipse as Administrator

Comment: I DO NOT BELIEVE. THIS WORKED

Answer (score 4):

Just Close your Eclipse . And  Start Eclipse as Run As Administrator your problem will be solved.
Eclipse doesn't have access to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation.. and doesnt copy the configuration file into backup.

To Set Eclipse to run as administrator go to eclipse Right Click on Eclipse Select Properties -->Compatibility -->privilege level -->Select Run this program As Administrator -->apply -->ok
then you are all set...

And if you want to change this setting for all users then go to eclipse Right Click on Eclipse Select Properties -->Compatibility -->change setting for all users-->privilege level -->Select Run this program As Administrator -->apply -->ok...
Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in Tomcat 7.0 and Eclipse Mars. Restarting Eclipse as Administrator resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your Eclipse is trying to write into the "Program Files" folder, which is protected by default by the Windows operating system.

The solution:

Navigate to the "Program Files" folder. Right-click on the "Apache Software Foundation" folder. Click on Properties. Go to the security tab. Click on "Edit...". Select "Users" in the "Names of groups or users" listbox. In the other "Permissions for users" listbox, check "Full Control". Click Apply/OK.

Answer (score 0):

Put Tomcat in a folder **without** empty spaces in a the *path*. So:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\backup
```

Shoud be something like:

```
C:\Tomcat\backup
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two installation kinds of Tomcat.
1. Windows Installation file with setup.exe
2. A collection of files without setup.exe

What you should use as a server is the second one (A collection of files without setup.exe).
Because it is the one that includes the /backup/ folder and its contents.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on server at view..and change the port number

Answer (score 0):

On windows 8.1 it worked by setting compatibility mode to windows 8.1 and then giving privileges to administrator by going to properties on right click on eclipse.exe and then going to the compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try these 3 methods

1) Try deleting the .snap file found in

yourprojectworkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources

2) The most common hiccup is when another web server (or any process for that matter) has laid claim to port 8080.  This is the default HTTP port that Tomcat attempts to bind to at startup.  To change this, open the file:

```
   $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml
```

and search for '8080'.  Change it to a port that isn't in use, and is greater than 1024, as ports less than or equal to 1024 require superuser access to bind under UNIX. (Example 8181)

Restart Tomcat and you're in business.  Be sure that you replace the "8080" in the URL you're using to access Tomcat.  For example, if you change the port to 8181, you would request the URL http://localhost:8181/ in your browser.

3) Open the bin folder which contains the shutdown.bat file residing inside the tomcat directory. Run it, that should solve the port problem.